# How to type a function using alias in fish shell?

Tags: fish

```
# type repeat ;echo "this is a bash shell output"
repeat is a function
repeat () 
{ 
    local n i;
    n="$1";
    shift;
    for ((i = 1; i <= "$n"; ++i))
    do
        echo Date starting `date`;
        echo Before waiting `date`;
        sleep 6;
        echo Done waiting `date`;
        /usr/bin/mpv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga;
        /usr/bin/mpv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga;
        /usr/bin/mpv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga;
        "$@";
    done
}
```

I would like to add this function for the alias repeat in fish shell. This alias is already available in bash shell but I would like to use the same in fish shell also. # indicates its the root user. For normal users its Fish shell which has been set as default.

Comment: try this under the function: `alias repeat='repeat'`

Comment: want me to type it after > or inside a file ?

Comment: Let me get you right you want thsi written in fish shell syntax?

Comment: yeah it needs to be written in fish shell syntax as repeat alias

Comment: try my updated and let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function repeat  
set n "$argv[1]";  
set m "$argv[2]";  
for i in (seq $n) ; set i $i+1  
echo "Starting date";date  
sleep 5;  
echo "Before Waiting";date  
sleep 10  
echo "After Waiting";date  
/usr/bin/mpv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga;  
/usr/bin/mpv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga;  
/usr/bin/mpv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga;  
eval $m  
end
end
```

Well this is the answer I have come up with and it works. It uses the mpv media player.
Let me know if any further changes can be done.